# Какие у ocstore 2.3 уязвимости, что начали появляться эксплойты?

Tags: вирусы, уязвимости, ocstore

Вот такие файлы со случайными названиями http://prntscr.com/na0zy9

и таким содержанием http://prntscr.com/na11ao

стали появляться на почти нулевом сайте. (есть только шаблон unishop+Модуль "Автоматческая загрузка прайсов")

в index.php нашел include http://prntscr.com/na13b2

Посоветуйте как избавится от напасти этой, способы защиты.

Есть вероятность, что это хостер с брешью?